# How to get this sort of format using dojox TableContainer?

Tags: dojo

I need to have something like :

textbox

textbox button

checkbox

I am using the dojox.layout.TableContainer to contain the elements.
The code I wrote is in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sNACz/71/

I cant seem to get the format right. The class and age boxes are indented to the right. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cols to modify the number of columns of yout Table, for example 3, 6, any number you need... and tweak the labelWidth a bit : http://jsfiddle.net/sNACz/85/
I hope this helps, also note that you can play with colspans if needed too :)
TableContainer is quite flexible, as long as you do not try removing fields after it has started.

I guess in your case a cols: 2 should be enough, since you are nesting tableContainers... Play with it a bit, and do not hesitate checking the code for more possibilities (colspans etc)...